# java.util.regex.Pattern doesn't agree with online regex debugger

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with some regex for a program, I want the program to detect a certain exe, called gruell[something].exe

So I ended up with the following regex:

```
gruell.*\.exe[^\.]
```

After testing on both these sites my test cases are detected properly

- https://regex101.com/
- https://regexr.com/

My test set: (and what should fail and pass)

- gruell-Core.exe [PASS]
- Gruell.exe [PASS]
- gruell_x64.exe [PASS]
- Gruell_x64-core.exe [PASS]
- grull.exe [FAIL]
- gruell_____.exe [PASS]
- gruell_installer.msi [FAIL]
- gruell.html [FAIL]
- .gruell.exe.398sn [FAIL]
- gru-ell.exe [FAIL]

When I run this on my machine using the java.util.regex.Pattern it will not find anything, eventhough the folder I told it to scan contains both:

- gruell.exe
- .gruell.exe.398sn

Now the intersting part is is when I remove [^.] it will detect, however, it detects the .gruell.exe.398sn aswell, which is what I don't want.

Code in question:

```
File f = new File("G:\\dev\\gruell");
recursive_scan(f);
```

The function:

```
for (file : location.listFiles())
{
    if (file.isDirectory)
    {
         recursive_scan(file)
    }
    else
    {
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("gruell.*\\.exe[^\\.]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
         if (pattern.matcher(file.name).find())
         {
              System.out.println("FOUND: " + file.name);   
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: ..i think it's "just" 3(!) backslashes (to escape 4 java:)

Comment: Regexr supports two flavors of regex, and regex101 supports several more, but *neither* of them supports the Java flavor, nor caters to the details of using `java.util.regex.Pattern`.  With that said, you're most likely running into issues with (not) escaping the regex as needed when expressing it in String form.

Comment: So, how would I go about testing the java specific version of regex?

Comment: Google will readily find you online regex testers oriented toward Java.  [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) is one such.  Among its particular features is providing the appropriate Java String form for regexes you test there.

Comment: After checking with RegexPlanet it does say that the correct version of the regex string is this: "gruell.*\\.exe[^.]" which I have, however, it does show up as not detecting any of the test strings, so that is something at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright thanks to the site provided by John Bollinger https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html I was able to find out 2 things that were wrong here.

First off I had to use:

```
 pattern.matcher(file.name).matches()
```

Instead of what I had:

```
 pattern.matcher(file.name).find()
```

And second off I had to remove [^.] from the end of the String.

From:

```
"gruell.*\\.exe[^.]"
```

To:

```
"gruell.*\\.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

> After testing on both [regex101 and RegExr] my test cases are detected properly

That seems unlikely, since your pattern is indeed faulty, not only in Java's Regex dialect but also in the ones tested by those sites.  The only plausible explanation I see is that you were not actually testing the cases you think you were.  For example, your test inputs may have had trailing spaces or newlines.

Which brings me to the problem with your pattern.  As you already observe,

> Now the intersting part is is when I remove [^.] it will detect,

That's because that sub-expression matches a character (different from `.`).  Your overall pattern therefore indeed does not match `"gruell-Core.exe"` because there is no character after the `.exe`.  Try matching `"gruell-Core.exee"` instead.

If you want your matches to end with `.exe`, then anchor your pattern instead: `gruell.*\.exe$`